# Nuclear dimension of $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

[image]

I met with troubles in the the
proof of forward implication.
By definition of nuclear dimension of $C^*$-algebras, it is easy to see that (1) and (3) hold, how to prove (2) and (4)?[image]

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0001870815301250  @Aweygan The lemma ilan Hirshberga and JianchaoWu's paper.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in B_0$ and let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.  Since $\dim_{\operatorname{nuc}}(B)\leq d$, there is a finite dimensional $C^*$-algebra $F=F^{(0)}\oplus\cdots\oplus F^{(d)}$ and c.p. maps $\psi:B\to F$, $\varphi:F\to B$ with $\psi$ contractive, $\varphi\mid_{F^{(i)}}$ order zero for $i=0,1,\ldots,d$, and $\|\varphi\circ\psi(x_k)-x_k\|<\varepsilon$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$.  Since the nuclear dimension of any finite-dimensional $C^*$-algebra is zero, we have
$$\sum_{l=0}^d(\dim_{\operatorname{nuc}}(F^{(l)})+1)(0+1)=d+1.$$

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand how to find each $\psi^(l)$ and $\phi^(l)$? Can we think of it in the following way: each $F^(i), i=1, 2, \cdots$ is a direct sum of matrix algebras?

Comment: The map $\psi^{(l)}$ is the map $\psi$ composed with the projection from $F$ to $F^{(l)}$, and $\phi^{(l)}$ is the restriction of $\phi$ to $F^{(l)}$.  Each $F^{(i)}$ is a finite-dimensional $C^*$-algebra, hence is a direct sum of matrix algebras.

Comment: Well, but $F=F^{(0)}\oplus\cdots\oplus F^{(d)}$, how to get the decompoaition of  $A_{\epsilon}?

Comment: $A_\varepsilon=F$, with $A_\varepsilon^{(i)}=F^{(i)}$.

Comment: But the supersript is $m$, rather than  $d$.

Comment: $m=d$.  The only "trick" in this proof is that the nuclear dimension of finite-dimensional algebra is zero.  The rest is just translating notation.